# How to use inbuilt keywords or functions of Oracle in QueryOver of NHibernate in C#?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I am using Oracle as a DB.
How to transform following hibernate query  in QueryOver of NHibernate.

```
string condition = "RepositoryItemDO.RepositoryType = :REPTYPE AND 
24*(SYSDATE-RepositoryItemDO.FingerPrint.CreatingDateTime) >= :HOURS"
                    + " AND RepositoryItemDO.TargetEncryption IS NOT NULL AND RepositoryItemDO.TargetStorage IS NOT NULL";
```

How to write syntax for above query in QueryOver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VarArgsSQLFunction to use arithmatics operation in QueryOver and also for the accessing sysdate we can use NoArgSQLFunction which is already defined in OracleDilect.

Below is the sample query which you can try using queryover

```
var func = Projections.SqlFunction(new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.Double, "(", "-", ")"), NHibernateUtil.DateTime, Projections.SqlFunction("sysdate", NHibernateUtil.DateTime), Projections.Property<AdministrativeCaseEO>(c => c.EffectiveCasePeriod.EffectiveStartDate));

var parfunc = Projections.SqlFunction(new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.Double, "(", "*", ")"), NHibernateUtil.Decimal, func, Projections.Constant(24));

var conjunction = Restrictions.Conjunction()
.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<RepositoryItemDO>(c => c.RepositoryType ), yourRefType))
.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull(Projections.Property<RepositoryItemDO>(c => c.TargetEncryption)))
.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull(Projections.Property<RepositoryItemDO>(c => c.TargetStorage)))
.Add(dateConj);
```